# Determining whether a string can be rearranged into a palindrome

Tags: java, strings, interview-questions, palindrome

For a string, count the number of occurences of each character. If at most one character has odd count then the string can be a palindrome else it's not.

```
public class Palindrome {
        //count the chars in the input string
            //if not more than one character has odd count then palindrome is possible
            public static boolean isPalindromPossible(String input)
            {
                int[] charCount = new int[128];
                for(int i = 0 ; i < input.length() ; i++)
                {
                    charCount[(int)input.charAt(i)]++;
                }
                int oddCount = 0 ;
                for(int i  = 0 ; i < 128 ; i++)
                {
                    if(charCount[i] % 2!=0)
                    {
                        oddCount++;
                    }
                }

                if(oddCount != 0 && oddCount != 1)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                String input = "aacaacc";
                System.out.println(isPalindromPossible(input));
            }
    }
```

Comment: What would happen with abba?

Comment: returns true as there is not character with odd count

Comment: Determining if the string is really a palindrome is actually less work than counting oddness of letters to determine if it *might* be a palindrome.

Comment: @saneGuy return (input.equals(new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString() ? true : false);

Comment: @Zack this is not the question being asked.

Comment: @saneGuy aside from the one liner, above, do you need a fuller explanation?

Comment: @Zack my question is how does palindrome check solve this question

Comment: @saneGuy it doesn't solve the problem as you have stated (determining if it is possibly a palindrome).  It is more of a comment that maybe you are trying to solve the wrong problem.  I see that you tagged this as an interview question, so perhaps you have no control over it, but in that case it reeks of the same logic behind asking an interviewee about [weighing airplanes](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/206840/what-is-the-intention-behind-asking-weight-of-plane)

Comment: @Zack  got it. 

Comment: @saneGuy related you your actual code, note that it will fail if the string contains unicode characters

Comment: @Zack  true. The assumption is ASCII alphabet .

Answer (score 5):

- **`int`**

  All the counters are inherently non-negative. I recommend to make them `unsigned`, just to clarify your intentions.
- **What to return**

  - **Computing return value**

    ```
        if (condition) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    ```

    is a long way to say

    ```
        return !condition;
    ```
  - **Actual condition**

    ```
        oddCount != 0 && oddCount != 1
    ```

  is a long way to say

  ```
          oddCount > 1
  ```

  So I recommend to simply

  ```
      return oddCount < 2;
  ```
- **Efficiency**

  I wouldn't bother about performance at all. However, you *may* shave few cycles:

  ```
      ....
      charCount[(int)input.charAt(i)] ^= 1;
      ....
      oddCount += charCount[i];
  ```

  thus avoiding taking modulo and making decisions inside the loop. I don't think it will make any difference however.
- **Assumptions and restrictions**

  Traditionally *A man, a plan, a canal, Panama!* is considered a palindrome. You really need to say *what* is a palindrome in your setting.

Comment: There are [no unsigned ints in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/430346/1157100).

Comment: @200_success What a shame.